# Problema com icon awesome num select option

Tags: css, font-awesome

Estou a tentar adicionar um icon unicode awesome numa option do meu select mas fica-me sempre com este simbolo 

```css
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
font-weight: normal;
font-style : normal;
src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"),
url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"),
url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"),
url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}
```

```html
<select id="select_pt" class="select_pt" size="5" style="font-family:'FontAwesome';">
    <option value="alemanha">ALEMANHA</option>
    <option value="austria">ÁUSTRIA</option>
    <option value="belgica">BÉLGICA</option>
    <option value="bulgaria">BULGÁRIA</option>
    <option value="chipre">CHIPRE</option>
    <option value="croacia">CROÁCIA</option>
    <option value="dinamarca">DINAMARCA</option>
    <option value="eslovaquia">ESLOVÁQUIA</option>
    <option value="eslovenia">ESLOVÉNIA</option>
    <option value="espanha">ESPANHA</option>
    <option value="estonia">ESTÓNIA</option>
    <option value="finlandia">FINLÂNDIA</option>
    <option value="franca">FRANÇA</option>
    <option value="grecia">GRÉCIA</option>
    <option value="holanda">HOLANDA</option>
    <option value="hungria">HUNGRIA</option>
    <option value="irlanda">IRLANDA</option>
    <option value="italia">ITÁLIA</option>
    <option value="letonia">LETÓNIA</option>
    <option value="lituania">LITUÂNIA</option>
    <option value="luxemburgo">LUXEMBURGO</option>
    <option value="malta">MALTA</option>
    <option value="polonia">POLÓNIA</option>
    <option selected value="portugal">PORTUGAL &#xf00c;</option>
    <option value="reino_unido">REINO UNIDO</option>
    <option value="republica_checa">REPULICA CHECA</option>
    <option value="romenia">ROMÉNIA</option>
    <option value="suecia">SUECIA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: César aqui o ícone aparece perfeitamente sem o menor problema, editei sua pergunta para código executável, veja o que aparece pra você.

Comment: Vc quer o simbolo em todos os options, ou só quando clicar em um deles?